# Trouble manipulating imported csv data results in blank lines

Tags: object, powershell

I'm new to powershell so I am hoping I'm not missing anything very obvious.  I tried searching the site but it is difficult to find reference to this exact problem.  I'm trying to output only certain columns ( objects ) from a csv file with a pipe delimeter.  My actual file has some 40+ columns and multiple thousands of entries.  My hope is to use other powershell commands to sort and unique the data by only certain columns.  Unfortunately I cannot even get the simplest reduction of the data to work.

My sample file:

```
Letter | Number | IpAddress | Machine | User | Garbage
a | 5 | 127.0.0.1 | tower | Admin | randomcharacters
f | 193 | 127.0.0.2 | laptop | administrator | charactersrandom%
r | 2882 | 127.0.0.8 | workstation | user1 | nothi$gher@e
```

Both

```
import-csv .\sample.txt -Delimeter "|" | get-member
import-csv .\sample.txt -Delimeter "|" | select-object | get-member
```

Provide the same results

```
Name        MemberType   Definition                            
----        ----------   ----------                            
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)        
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()                     
GetType     Method       type GetType()                        
ToString    Method       string ToString()                     
Garbage     NoteProperty System.String Garbage=randomcharacters
IpAddress   NoteProperty System.String IpAddress =127.0.0.1    
Letter      NoteProperty System.String Letter =a               
Machine     NoteProperty System.String Machine =tower          
Number      NoteProperty System.String Number =5               
User        NoteProperty System.String User =Admin
```

But when I specify the object, System.String disappears and the output is just blank lines.

```
import-csv .\sample.txt -Delimiter "|" | select-object User | get-member


   TypeName: Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition                    
----        ----------   ----------                    
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()             
GetType     Method       type GetType()                
ToString    Method       string ToString()             
User        NoteProperty  User=null
```

Where am I going wrong?  I just want to import the data, and then output only a few columns.  Specifying one or more just fails.  I even tried to use the {$_.User} object as I had read on similar posts but it returns the same issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the property names are being created with a space at the end. So you would have to do this:

```
import-csv .\sample.txt -Delimiter "|" | select-object "User "
```

So how to fix this?

I suppose you could fix it manually or use some code like this prior to using `Import-Csv`:

```
(Get-Content -path .\sample.txt) -replace ' \| ','|' | Set-Content -Path .\sample.txt
```

This will also make sure your property values don't have extra space in them.

Comment: I did not realize it was keeping the trailing space.  I figured if the preceeding space was not used it would not use the trailing one.  Thanks ! I figured it was something simple, I was racking my brain.

Answer (score 0):

As Andy stated, you get to have property names and values with extra spaces. Here's another way of parsing the file.

```
Get-Content .\sample.txt | 
ForEach-Object {$_ -replace ' \| ','|'} | 
ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter '|'
```

Comment: Thanks again, sorry I cannot uprank your comment,